# Installing Ubuntu on older computer

Tags: installation, system-requirements

I am trying to install ubuntu on an older dell desktop from a CD.  I put the CD in and select install from CD and a purple screen comes up with the ubuntu symbol and a progress bar but it appears to be stuck on this screen.  The computer has a 2.8 GHz Pentium 4 processor, 1 GB of memory, and a 500 GB hard drive.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That computer has plenty of resource for Ubuntu.

What graphics card does the computer have?

Comment: you should try installing using [Alternate ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) and you can follow the instructions [here](http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/p2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to install from another CD or a USB flash drive. I'm running Lbuntu 11.10 on my older dektop (256 mb RAM,Pentium 4 2.3 Ghz). Your configuration is good enough to run any version of Ubuntu. So, please try another CD or USB flash drive.Let me know, what happen.

Comment: I believe I had a bad memory stick.  I removed it as well as did a few other things and it worked fine.  Computer is super slow though.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If your computer is super slow, then you should try any Lightweight distro like Lubuntu, Xubuntu. For more information please check [here](http://lxde.org/)